# Newly migrated WordPress site not working

Tags: wordpress

I have my godaddy wordpress website zip file. I extracted it to the /var/www/html folder on my AWS ubuntu server. 
I created the database using phomyadmin snd imported my db there. 
I have my domain name on GoDaddy account, I integrated the GoDaddy domain name to my AWS. 
I changed the Apache configuration file and gave the path to my /var/www/html/mywpsite

When i open my domain all th static files like css, js not working or loading ..
They give error 404

And when I check on the chrome debug tool, files show url like this

localhost/mywpsite/wp-content...

And sometimes when I open the domain it append the localhost to the main domain.

example:-

my domain name is - www.xyz.com

when I open the url it appends with the localhost like this localhost/xyz/wp-admin

If you want more details please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by 'when you open the URL'? In a browser?   BTW, this isn't an AWS-specific question; it's a WordPress config problem in all likelihood.

Comment: @KJH I want to run my wordpress website on AWS server. I checked my wp config. All are good.

Comment: Understood, but whether you moved it to AWS or some other provider probably wouldn't have mattered - I bet you would still have had this problem.  Anyway, your question needs more details. I'm still puzzled by your explanation. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use all in one wp migration plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) it will transfer your database and all media to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

I did much migration like this. The best way to do to

- Setup fresh Wordpress on your AWS account.
- Install WordPress backup plugin on your GoDaddy account.
- Install the same on your new WordPress website on AWS
- Take the backup using that plugin and restore it to the new AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

You may dump the database from GoDaddy and import it in AWS(probably EC2 instance),
Wordpress by it self does not store Data and uses SQL(MySQL or PostgreSQL). What you need is to migrate databases as well as WordPress by itself.
A mysqldump example may you get a perspective of what you need:

```
mysqldump -u wordpress_user -p worpress_database_name > /path/to/save/backup_wordpress.sql
```

You may need to have password as well.